# Why is my navigation bar not covering the whole screen?

Tags: html, css, angular, uinavigationbar

The following is the html and css code for the navigation bar.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


h2,
h3,
a {
 color: #727475;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}



.logo {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 1.45em;
}

.main-nav {
 margin-top: 5px;

}
.logo a,
.main-nav a {
 padding: 10px 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
}

.main-nav a {
 color: #456279;
 font-size: .99em;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
 color: #3b556e;
}



.header {
 padding-top: .5em;
 padding-bottom: .5em;
 border: 1px solid #929292;
 background-color: #252323;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}







@media (min-width: 769px) {
 .header,
 .main-nav {
  display: flex;
 }
 .header {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
     /* .header{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1150px;
 } */
 }

}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
 .header {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }

}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">Dairy Farm Dashboard</a></h1>
      <ul class="main-nav">
          
          <li>
              <select name="" id="" class="form form-control abcdefgh" [(ngModel)]="selecteddate"  (change)="mychange()">
                  <option value="" disabled>Date</option>
                  <option value="{{date}}" *ngFor="let date of date_new">{{date}}</option>
                 
                </select>
          </li>
          <li>
              <select name="" id="" class="form form-control abcdefgh" [(ngModel)]="selectcity"  (change)="citychange()">
                  <option value="" disabled>Country</option>
                  <option value="{{city.country}}" *ngFor="let city of city">{{city.city}}</option>
                  
                 
                </select>
          </li>
          <li><a (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
  </header>
```

The output that I am getting is somewhat like this.
[image: The output image.]

As it is clear from the picture,my navigation bar is not covering the whole screen.However even this would have been acceptable to me . The problem is that when I try to increase the browser size by pressing 'CTRL+' ,the navigation bar is not able to cover up the content below it.The following is the screenshot on expanded screens.
[image: View on enlarged screens.]

What am I doing wrong here?How do I make the navigation bar cover the entire screen.

Comment: Your code snipper doesn't match your explanation. In the snippet it does cover the whole navigator.

Comment: Have you tried to set in the parent component a class with something like this? `.fullPage {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}`

Comment: Why are you pressing `Ctrl +`? That's not *increasing* browser size; if you want to test multiple resolutions use the Developer Tools

Answer (score 1):

add any one from below in your `css` because some browser has default margins.

```
body{
margin:0;
}
```

or

```
*{
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: That is not working.I guess the problem has got something to do with appearance of a scrollbar on pressing the 'CNTRL+' key.If i press the 'CNTRL-' key that the scrollbar disappears and the navigation bar takes up the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code.

I have just added margin: 0; to body as by default browsers add some margins to it. It is working fine now.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

h2,
h3,
a {
 color: #727475;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}



.logo {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 1.45em;
}

.main-nav {
 margin-top: 5px;

}
.logo a,
.main-nav a {
 padding: 10px 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
}

.main-nav a {
 color: #456279;
 font-size: .99em;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
 color: #3b556e;
}



.header {
 padding-top: .5em;
 padding-bottom: .5em;
 border: 1px solid #929292;
 background-color: #252323;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}







@media (min-width: 769px) {
 .header,
 .main-nav {
  display: flex;
 }
 .header {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
     /* .header{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1150px;
 } */
 }

}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
 .header {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }

}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">Dairy Farm Dashboard</a></h1>
      <ul class="main-nav">
          
          <li>
              <select name="" id="" class="form form-control abcdefgh" [(ngModel)]="selecteddate"  (change)="mychange()">
                  <option value="" disabled>Date</option>
                  <option value="{{date}}" *ngFor="let date of date_new">{{date}}</option>
                 
                </select>
          </li>
          <li>
              <select name="" id="" class="form form-control abcdefgh" [(ngModel)]="selectcity"  (change)="citychange()">
                  <option value="" disabled>Country</option>
                  <option value="{{city.country}}" *ngFor="let city of city">{{city.city}}</option>
                  
                 
                </select>
          </li>
          <li><a (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
  </header>
```

Comment: Sorry this is still not working.I tried it as well.I guess the problem has something to do with the browser scrollbar.